# Is there a linear transformation $T$ from $ R^3$ into $R^2$ such that $T(1,-1,1) = (1,0)$ and $T(1,1,1)= (0,1)$ .

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a linear transformation $T$ from $ R^3$ into $R^2$ such that
$T(1,-1,1) = (1,0)$ and $T(1,1,1)= (0,1)$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$(a,b,c)=\frac{a-b}{2}(1,-1,1) +\frac{a-b}{2}(1,1,1)+(c-a)(0,0,1)$$

Then $$T(a,b,c)=\frac{a-b}{2}T(1,-1,1) +\frac{a-b}{2}T(1,1,1)+(c-a)T(0,0,1)$$

Picking any value you want for $T(0,0,1)$ gives you the desired transformation.

Answer (score 2):

A linear transformation is uniquely specified by its action on a basis. We can extend the set of linearly independent vectors $\{(1, -1, 1), (1,1,1) \}$ to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ by adjoining some vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$ to the set. The required linear transformation can then be specified by setting $T(v)$ to be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Sure: $$T=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 0 \\1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

More generally: given $n$ independent vectors you can always find a linear transformation mapping these to $n$ linear independent vectors.

Comment: You have to drop the second "independent" word, in the second line, so that this applies to the case asked by the OP.

Comment: You're correct. Sorry. I'll edit as soon as I find a good formulation.